# How to customize WPF TreeView columns individually?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, treeview

I have the Xaml code that show everything correctly but I want to make it so the first column's content is bold:

```
<c:TreeView Name="JobList" SelectedItemChanged="JobList_SelectedItemChanged">
    <c:TreeView.Columns>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Jobs" Width="350" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Goal" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Goal}"/>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Messages" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MessageType}"/>
    </c:TreeView.Columns>
</c:TreeView>
```

Also can I also do this based on whether the item in the first column has sub treeview nodes or not?

Comment: Where does this TreeListView class come from ?

Comment: Sorry it's a custom control I got from the net (free and open source) but it's very close to standard TreeView. I should edit the code.

Comment: Btw it's from here, in case anyone would wanna use it: http://windowsclient.net/blogs/ricciolocristian/archive/2008/03/22/a-complete-wpf-treelistview-control.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I havent used the TreeListView, but usually you can put other UIElements in the header. Give this a try:

```
        <GridViewColumn Header="Jobs" Width="350" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}">
        <GridViewColumn.Header>
            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Goal}"></TextBlock>
        </GridViewColumn.Header>
    </GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: Thanks it's telling me GridViewColumn.Header isn't found, probably because of the control I am using. But at least I got the idea. Thanks.